# Input string was not in a correct format when trying to add jQuery in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try this and it gives the error mentioned in the title at the line I call `String.Format`.

```
public static void JqueryDialogue(string divId)
{
    String script = String.Format(
        "$(document).ready(function(){ $('#{0}').dialog('open'); });", 
        divId);

    // Gets the executing web page
    Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
    string codeId = "openDialoge" + divId.ToString();

    // Checks if the handler is a Page and that the script isn't already on Page
    if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(codeId))
    {
        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
            typeof(JavascriptHelper), 
            codeId, 
            script,
            true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `String.Format` you'll need to escape the `{` and `}` characters that you want to be outputted literally since they are Javascript code. To achieve this you use `{{` and `}}` respectively.

You can read more about string formatting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569608.aspx) where an odd behavior resulting from escaping curly braces is also explained.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to escape the `{` after function declaration something like

```
String script = String.Format("$(document).ready(function()
{{ $('#{0}').dialog('open'); }});", divId);
```